# How to get all route assign to same index action of controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Below is my default route code ...

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "TEST", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

How to set all router like http://1.2.3.4/TEST/111 or http://102.3.4/TEST/222
all to index action of TEST controller?

Comment: Create another route before the defaulr - `url: "TEST/{id}` with the same defaults

Comment: Just create new route without the `{controller}` portion above it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, since Stephen won't answer: Create a route before your default route, which matches your url

```
routes.MapRoute(
            //this will always match the controller 'TEST' with its action 'Index'
            name: "TEST",
            url: "TEST/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "TEST", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

        );routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "TEST", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

If the url doesn't match your first route it will check against the pattern of your second route.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I try http:// ip/TEST/upload on browser.... but it did not map to index action of TEST controller. did I do something wrong?

Comment: What happens if you remove `/upload` or set it to `Test/1` ? If my memory serves me correct, id  is supposed to be a numeric value

Comment: `id` does not have to be numeric. This will work fine assuming your routes are in the correct order.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for clearing that up. Wasn't sure of it myself.